# Reference a key in an numerical array

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I was trying to use a variable to reference a specific key in an array like so:

```
$var =& $array[0];
```

The example array:

```
$array = array('a', 'b');
```

The functionality I was hoping for was that $var would be a until $array[0] is changed.  However this does not appear to work.

```
echo $var; // echoes a
array_shift($array);
echo $var; // still echoes a, not b
```

Is referencing a specific key possible?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking... `=&` is an alias. `$var` becomes an alias for what `$array[0]` points to when you set up the alias, so yes, fairly obviously `$var` is going to keep saying "a". That's what it points to.

Comment: What I hear you asking for is a special syntax that will always refer to a specific index of a specific array-variable. Is that correct?

Comment: =& is an alias, aka reference http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php.  My understanding was that they could reference a variable rather than store the value since they aren't copies.  So I was hoping $var would just return whatever $array[0] would even after modifying the 0 key.

Comment: They reference a place in memory. Arrays have a layer of indirection beyond the memory addresses... they have a cursor. Just changing the cursor does not change the contents of memory at the location where 'a' was stored.

Comment: Thank you @ctrahey, so I take it this isn't possible then.

Comment: check the 4th user comment, explaining exactly what you're doing http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Comment: Why? You _already have_ standard reference to element of array. It's .. __key__. Use just `$array[$key]` to reference desired `$key`. That's it. No sense in attempting re-define standard mechanism

Comment: @AlmaDo Just trying to see if it was possible to take a shortcut one step further since my function reuses [0] about 10 times as it shifts different types of elements off the array.

Comment: You _have_ this "shortcut". It's `$array[0]`

Comment: @AlmaDo exactly. Devon this is precisely what I was getting at. THE way to always refer to a given position in an array is to use the index syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$array = array('a', 'b');
$var = &$array;

echo $var[0]; // echoes a
array_shift($array);
echo  $var[0]; // echoes b
```

Comment: Thanks for showing that this works.  I was wondering if it was possible for $array[0] to be referenced like this rather than the entire array.

Comment: If you have satisfaction with this answer then accept answer

Comment: It doesn't answer the question at hand, referencing a specific key.  It is referencing the array.

Comment: Don't understand the down vote here. maybe explain why yours works and his doesn't.